# Python if/else in cmd

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can only reach the if statement in cmd and as soon as I hit enter it gives me an error, cant write the else statement.

```
a = 6
  if a>= 7:
     print("int")
```

It stops there and gives an error.

Comment: What's your error?  After copying and pasting, I get an indentation error.

Comment: Share the error please

Comment: IndentationError
I'm not sure how indent it because after i declare a and hit enter the next line comes up with the 3 arrows ">>>" and then i type in my if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the indentation and try:

```
a = 6
if a>= 7:
    print("int")
```

Python is indentation sensitive. All statements of a block need to have the same indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou to everyone who helped
Alright I figured it out.
after i complete the if statement i need to hit the "tab" button int the next line before i type my print statement.
Same thing with else.

```
a=6
if a>=7:
    print("int")
else:
    print("happy")
```